# Populate field in SQL with zero

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a SQL query which provides brand name and count of order(Case-1).

I have to prepare an hourly report with this but , if I don't have count for one hour for any brand the specific brand will not be displayed(Case-2).

In this case how I can automatically populate brand2 with zero in the alert mail ?

Sample SQL

```
SELECT distinct(brand), count(*) Hourly Count
FROM table_name where date_time between systimestamp-1/24 and systimestamp
GROUP BY brand;
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and make it clear what your data looks like and what you are trying to produce.  Providing sample data as a text table is recommended.  And show your current query.

Comment: Shared the details :) @GordonLinoff

Comment: You likely will need to generate a reference set to join to, so you can consistently have each hour represented, then do the count by hour.

Comment: Can you give me a sample query please @Vinnie

Comment: Create `table_name` with defualt as `0` for the `Brand` column , so for all the case where there is no data you will have `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls find below what I was looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BRAND_NAME),SUM(COUNT)FROM(
    SELECT distinct(BRAND_NAME) ,count(*) COUNT
    FROM TABLE
    UNION ALL
      SELECT BRAND_NAME,0 AS COUNT
    FROM (SELECT 'Brand1' AS BRAND_NAME FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Brand2' AS BRAND_NAME FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Brand3' AS BRAND_NAME FROM DUAL)
    TEMP1)
    TEMP2
    GROUP BY BRAND_NAME
    ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, using `select distinct` with `group by` is almost never needed (certainly not in this case where one column is needlessly surrounded by parentheses) and shows a lack of understanding of both constructs.

One method to do what you want is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT brand,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date_time between systimestamp-1/24 and systimestamp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HourlyCount
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY brand;
```

Another method assumes you have a table with all the brands:

```
SELECT b.brand, count(t.brand) as HourlyCount
FROM brands b LEFT JOIN
     table_name 
     ON b.brand = t.brand AND
        t.date_time between systimestamp-1/24 and systimestamp
GROUP BY b.brand;
```